# Генератор рерайтов PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Не могу выполнить задание:

Дано:

```
$x = '{p1 | p2 | p3} some text there {p4 | p5 | p6} and some text there {p7 | p8 | p9}';
```

Нужно чтобы рандомно выбирались значения в фигурных скобках. Т.е нужно раскрыть скобки и выбрать одно значение рандомно. Скобок в тексте может быть и 1000. На выходе должно получится вот так:

```
p3 some text there p5 and some text there p7
```

Советуют сделать через регулярки и explode(

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут можно объединить поиск и замену в один вызов `preg_replace_callback`. Также заметьте, что экранировать фигурные скобки необязательно, и модификатор жадности можно и не использовать, если заменить точку исключающим символьным классом `[^{}]` (*любой символ, отличный от `{` и `}`*).

См. [демо на PHP](https://ideone.com/Dmaykr):

```
$x = '{p1 | p2 | p3} some text there {p4 | p5 | p6} and some text there {p7 | p8 | p9}';
$x = preg_replace_callback('~{([^{}]+)}~', function($g) {
        $f = explode(' | ', trim($g[1]));
        $f = $f[(rand(0,count($f) - 1))];
        return $f;
    }, $x);

echo $x;
```

Обратите внимание, `trim()` и `' | '` использованы для того, чтобы в результате исключить появление лишних пробелов.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался сам, кому надо, забирайте)

```
<?php

        function genWords($x) {

        preg_match_all('~\{(.+)\}~U', $x, $g); // Парсим скобки

        for($i = 0; $i < count($g[1]); $i++) { //генерируем 
        $f = explode('|', $g[1][$i] );
        $f = $f[(rand(0,count($f) - 1))];
        $x = preg_replace('~\{(.+)\}~U',  $f, $x, 1);


        }   
            echo $x;
        }

        echo genWords('{ p1 | p2 | p3 } some text there { p4 | p5 | p6 } and some text there { p7 | p8 | p9 }');

        ?>
```